# Completing a regular expression in IIS7.5 that succeed in matching, but fails in the subsequent rewrite

Tags: regex, iis, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

I have a folder with an image in it called:

```
/products/12345/800.jpg
```

where 12345 = a database id and 800.jp is a 800 pixell wide image.

I want to create a nice url like this:

```
/products/12345/800/this-is-a-nice-readable-url.jpg
```

In IIS7, I have created the following regular expression:

```
(.*)/products/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)([/\-\.0-9a-z]*)
```

I get a match when I test against the following URL:

```
http://localhost/products/12345/800/this-is-a-nice-readable-url.jpg
```

So I created the following rewriteurl:

```
{R:1}/products/{R:2}/{R:3}.jpg
```

But that does not seem to work. I thought that the above rewrite would get me to:

```
http://localhost/products/12345/800.jpg
```

But it does not. So I guess my issue is that I have succeeded in creating a match, but I have failed and replacing the source with the target.

How can I make this rewrite work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url part which is used to match your pattern doesn't contain leading `/`, so you are indeed very close to success, try to use this pattern:

```
(.*/)?products/(\d+)/(\d+).*
```

and rewrite:

```
/{R:1}products/{R:2}/{R:3}.jpg
```

Comment: You are beyond awesome. Thanks.